# Avoid duplicating code in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a code listing that is full of code like the following, but larger chunks.

```
if (m = '00000') then 
  done <= '1';
else
  done <= '0';
end if;
```

Is there any way of making this like a function of a c like #define so that I don't have to write the same code all over the place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not VHDL in the first place, so you have other things to worry about. (It's a bit more VHDL-like after the edit)

Thankfully VHDL has nothing like C's #define. Instead it has tools for proper abstractions such as packages (very roughly, C++ namespaces but done right), functions and procedures.

This allows you to write

```
done <= test_zero(m);
```

assuming `done` is a signal ( or `done := test_zero(m);` if it's a variable)

test_zero is then a function, something like

```
function test_zero ( word : in std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
begin
   if word = (word'range => '0') then
      return '1';
   else 
      return '0';
   end if;
end test_zero;
```

which (because it uses the "range" attribute) will work with different sizes of "m".

You will end up with a collection of useful functions : keep them in a package and use them throughout the project.

A package usually appears as two parts : the package specification (a bit like a C header file done right)

```
package my_tools is

   function test_zero ( word : in std_logic_vector) return std_logic;

end my_tools;
```

and a package body containing the implementations

```
package body my_tools is

   function test_zero ( word : in std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
      ...
   end test_zero;

end my_tools;
```

To use it, it is compiled into a library (we'll use the default library "work" which is already declared by an implicit `library work;` in every VHDL file). Then you can choose either to make everything in the package visible in your code:

```
use work.my_tools.all;
```

Or make only one function visible:

```
use work.my_tools.test_zero;
```

Or make it obvious to anyone reading the code where the mysterious "test_zero" function came from:

```
done <= my_tools.test_zero(m);
```

If you have used C++ namespaces you will recognise these different strategies.

What makes the VHDL equivalent "namespaces done right" is that the VHDL compiler uses these declarations to track dependencies automatically and compile the right bits, instead of needing additional #includes and external tools like makefiles which must be kept in sync with the actual code by hand.